# Why can't I output data from this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help with how this array works:

```
    String[][] stringz = new String[5][4];
    System.out.println(stringz[x][y]);
```

When I try to output using `stringz[1][3]`, I have the **null** data output.

when I try to output using `stringz[0][3]`, I also have the **null** data output.

I know that in arrays index begins by **0**.

So I also want to output the data in `[0][4]`

But java compilation shows me an error? Why? If i have 5 data boxes (5-1) = index #4 should be the last?

Comment: The largest indices you can use, given your declaration of `stringz`, is [4][3]. You are violating this constraint by using a number greater than 3 for the 2nd index.

Comment: Thank u bro, i just confused with 1array type and multidimensional type.

Comment: To clarify, if you have an array initialized with `new String [m][n]`, the largest indices in this array would be `array[m-1][n-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two dimensional array's indexes are below.

0,0__0,1__0,2__0,3

1,0__1,1__1,2__1,3

2,0__2,1__2,2__2,3

3,0__3,1__3,2__3,3

4,0__4,1__4,2__4,3

So, you don't have fourth index in your second dimension.